# Bluetooth Smart: Android connection issue to multiple slave devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

we are currently developing an Android App which has to establish multiple connections to different Bluetooth Smart devices (5 devices). Our problem is the connection establishment mechanism. Sometimes the connections can be established very quickly (~10s @ 1s advertisement interval). Unfortunately in many cases the connection can either not be established to all devices or it takes too much time (~60 seconds).   Apart from that with some android devices we are not able to discover the Gatt services reliable.  Has anyone seen similar issues?    Best regards

Answer (score 0):

android version?
some devices like nexus 5 have some problem with bluetooth ...for example

http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/12/28/bug-watch-many-nexus-devices-still-suffer-from-assorted-bluetooth-issues/

Comment: I checked the fuctionality with different smartphones with Android >=4.4 with Nexus 5 phone it works quite well (nevertheless sometimes the connection cannot be closed)